# Kafka producer Failed to collate messages by topic, partition due to: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(logmessage)]

Tags: apache-kafka, partition, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to send messages into the topic and here is the error that i get every now and then.

Please provide any suggestions that you think can resolve this issue.
Here is the stacktrace of the error:

- Failed to collate messages by topic, partition due to: fetching topic
  metadata for topics [Set(logmessage)] from broker
  [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:XX.X.XX.XX,port:XX)] failed 2016-10-05
  21:49:04 - fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(logmessage)] from
  broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:host:XX.X.XX.XX,port:XX] failed
  kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics
  [Set(logmessage)] from broker
  [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:XX.X.XX.XX,port:XX] failed at
  kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:72) at
  kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.updateInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:82)
  at
  kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$handle$2.apply$mcV$sp(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
  at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallow(Utils.scala:172) at
  kafka.utils.Logging$class.swallowError(Logging.scala:106) at
  kafka.utils.Utils$.swallowError(Utils.scala:45) at
  kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
  at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:77) at
  kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:33) at
  com.startsmartinc.logger.SSLogger.logMessageBundleBolt(SSLogger.java:222)
  at
  com.ssi.parsing.MessageBundle.logEventstoAPI(MessageBundle.java:414)
  at
  com.ssi.parsing.MessageBundle.processBundle(MessageBundle.java:113)
  at com.ssi.parsing.MessageBundle.Parse(MessageBundle.java:42) at
  com.ssi.threads.WorkerThreads.run(WorkerThreads.java:29) at
  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at
  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
  java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException at
  kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100) at
  kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73) at
  kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
  at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113) at
  kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)

---

Comment: we are also getting the same error? did you solve this error?

Comment: I cannot say it a solution, because all i did was clear all the temporary kafka logs (tmp) and restarted the Kafka from scratch and there after I never encountered this again.